# Windows 8.1 Enteprise update from 8.0 fails with no error

Tags: windows, upgrade, windows-8.1-upgrade

I'm trying to update a Windows 8.0 Enterprise to Windows 8.1 Enterprise with no success.

The setup starts, shows a Windows log for a short time, shows a really quick progress (98%) and then fails with no additional message.

The file named C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log does not show any error message, only informative ones, no error is shown in the event viewer, what I can try to do now?

Regards
Massimo

Comment: upload the setuperr.log

Comment: I could upload it... but it's EMPTY, a 0 byte file! So I do not see the usefulness of the upload.

Comment: in this case it is difficult to see what went wrong.